# How to resolve Browserstack Local Testing SSLError("bad handshake")

Tags: python, ssl, fedora, browserstack

**When establishing remote webdriver connection via https:**

`self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='https://' + settings.BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME + ':' + settings.BROWSERSTACK_KEY + '@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=desired_cap)`

**This error message pops up:**

`MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='hub-cloud.browserstack.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))`

**From Browserstack's FAQ:**

*My firewall/IDP/proxy is rejecting SSL/HTTPS content from BrowserStack.com
This could be because of a missing certificate chain due to which your firewall/IDP/proxy may not recognize, or block the SSL/HTTPS content. This usually happens if your firewall/IDP/proxy is not updated regularly. In this case please install the ValiCert Legacy Certificate Chain from the GoDaddy repository and try again.*

Am I on the right track? (Following Browserstack's FAQ)

*OS: Fedora-30

Thank you in advance for any help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing the Hub URL from HTTPS to HTTP or whitelist *.browserstack.com over ports 80 and 443 over your network.
​

Comment: Thank you Heena Nanwani. I did What you suggested and it worked, i.e. changing to HTTP